# Solr Setup - Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

Trying to setup solr 6.4.1 on Windows Server 2008 with JDK 64bit 1.8.0

Having set system environment-variables:

```
CLASSPATH = "C:\solr-6.4.1\dist\solr-core-6.4.1.jar"
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
PATH = "...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin"
```

When trying to start via cmd (as admin) "solr start -p 8984" following error message appears:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
Failed removing old solr logs (...)
```

I have unzipped solr-core.6.4.1.jar and SolrCLI is actually in it.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you've [downloaded](http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/6.5.0/) and unzipped the correct package:

- Correct package "**solr-6.5.0.tgz**" usually weighs 140Mb
- Incorrect package to run the server "**solr-6.5.0-src.tgz**" (resources to compile)

Answer (score 0):

Add your Solr Server's bin folder to the `PATH` environment-variable:

`PATH = "...;<Path to extracted Solr>\bin"`

Don't need to set `C:\solr-6.4.1\dist\solr-core-6.4.1.jar` in CLASSPATH.

Comment: ok, I deleted CLASSPATH. And I added the Solr Servers bin folder to PATH variable. But the error message still appears when starting the server

Answer (score 0):

Why you set CLASSPATH to `solr-core-6.4.1.jar"` ?

```
Set JAVA_HOME correctly
```

Make sure Java is 1.8, you can check using `java -version`  from cmd

open cmd and  go to your Solr folder location `C:\solr-6.4.1\`

and enter`bin\solr start -p 8983`

Comment: ok, I removed CLASSPATH. What do you mean with 'Set JAVA_HOME' correctly - what is correctly? java -version is: 1.8.0_121-b13. Started with port 8983, but the error message still remains. Any other idea?

Comment: check if have downloaded other than solr-6.4.1.zip something like src.zip

Answer (score 0):

For me (on Fedora) the cause for

```
bin/solr status
...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.cli.SolrCLI
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.cli.SolrCLI
```

was that I was running it from my source code, after installation, but should run it inside [default](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/taking-solr-to-production.html) folder

```
cd /opt/solr-9.5.0
bin/solr status
```